# cannot update controls Patchvalue after getting json/object from api in Angular component

Tags: angular

I am new in Angular.

I have following form
form (ngSubmit) ="saveChanges" [formGroup]="form">

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Flight No*</mat-label>
    <input formControlName="flightno"  (blur)="getFlightDetails()"  mask ="AA0000" matInput>
    <mat-error *ngIf="form.invalid">
        {{getErrorMessageFieldName()}}
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>


<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Flight Date</mat-label>
    <input formControlName="gregdate" (blur)="getFlightDetails()" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker"/>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>origin*</mat-label>
     <input formControlName="origin" oninput="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()"
     matInput/>
    <mat-error>The origin field is required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Destination*</mat-label>
    <input formControlName="dest" oninput="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()" matInput />
    <mat-error>The destination field is required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

I have function to run when date or flightno change to get other details

getFlightDetails(){

```
const formValues = this.form.value;

if (formValues.gregdate!==null && formValues.flightno !==null)
  {
    const gdate =formatDate(formValues.gregdate,'yyyy-MM-dd','en');
    const fltnumber= formValues.flightno;
    this.dataservice.getfltdetails(gdate,fltnumber)
    .subscribe(fd =>{
      this.flightdetails=fd;
      console.log(this.flightdetails)
    })  
  }  

  //alert(this.flightdetails.origin)
  this.form.patchValue([
  {
    origin:this.flightdetails.origin,
    dest: this.flightdetails.destination
  }])
}
```

}

### Console log

acftReg: "HZAQ27    "
acftType: "33R       "
depArr: "D"
destination: "RUH       "
flightDate: "2021-07-25T00:00:00"
flightNo: "XXXX    "
origin: "JED       "

The console.log shows that I got data. but when I tried to patchvalue. It shows empty. Also when I check by alert(this.flightdetails.origin) also shows empty.. In flightdetails object all data show..Can anybody tell me what is the mistake. or what is the correct way.

Comment: you need to put your patchValue inside the subscribe. right now your patchValue is executed immediately instead of waiting for the observable to finish

Comment: I tried. with changes as you said. But still control not updated..

getFlightDetails(){
    const formValues = this.form.value;
    if (formValues.gregdate!==null && formValues.flightno !==null)
      {
        const gdate =formatDate(formValues.gregdate,'yyyy-MM-dd','en');
        const fltnumber= formValues.flightno;
        this.dataservice.getfltdetails(gdate,fltnumber)
        .subscribe(fd =>{
          this.flightdetails=fd;

       //change
          this.form.patchValue({origin: this.flightdetails.origin})
          console.log(this.flightdetails)
        })  
      }